# PostgreSql Подсоединение по адресу localhost:5432 отклонено

Tags: mysql, postgresql, intellij-idea, kotlin

Использую библиотеку Exposed от JetBrains и framework Ktor.

```
val dbPort = 5432
val dbName = "testdb"
//an example connection to Postgre
Database.connect("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:$dbPort/$dbName",
driver = "org.postgresql.Driver",user = "root", password = "your_pwd")
transaction {
    // print sql to std-out
    addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)

    SchemaUtils.create(Cities)
    // insert new city. SQL: INSERT INTO Cities (name) VALUES ('St. Petersburg')
    val stPeteId = Cities.insertAndGetId {
        it[name] = "St. Petersburg"
    }
    // 'select *' SQL: SELECT Cities.id, Cities.name FROM Cities
    println("Cities: ${Cities.selectAll()}")
}
```

При вызове SchemaUtils.create(Cities) возникает ошибка: PSQLException: Подсоединение по адресу localhost:5432 отклонено. Проверьте что хост и порт указаны правильно и что postmaster принимает TCP/IP-подсоединения.
Загуглив, понял , что надо поменять listen_addresses в файле postgresql.conf для прослушивания соединения TCP/IP. Но этого файла в папке с проектом нет и нету в External libraries в самой IDE. Где найти этот файл или можно как-то по другому решить эту проблему? Если как-то поможет, то если использовать подключение к MySQL:

`Database.connect("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", user = "root", password = "your_pwd")`, то на той же строке кода вызывается уже другая ошибка: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: localhost postgresql случает дефолтно. А вот запущена ли у вас база? Конфиг базы лежит либо в директории базы либо там, откуда его попросили читать при запуске базы.

Comment: Как мне проверить запущена ли она? В том то и дело , что директории базы нет, а откуда попросили читать тоже не узнать. Базу подключал через Gradle: compile "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.2"

Comment: Самое простое - посмотрите в списке запущенных процессов.

Comment: Я думаю нет. После Database.connect(...) в Debug можно увидеть , что идет сбор данных , а дальше выводиться сообщение Подсоединение по адресу localhost:5432 отклонено. Проверьте что хост и порт указаны правильно и что postmaster принимает TCP/IP-подсоединения.

Comment: Вот и я думаю, что у вас postgresql не запущен. При том подозреваю, что даже и не установлен.

Comment: Сталкивался с такой же ошибкой, помогло скачать сам postgres https://www.postgresql.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

У меня точно такая же проблема была. Нашёл ее по **C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data** . Но папка может варьироваться от версии PostgreSQL аналогично ну допустим если у вас версия 9 то путь будет выглядеть так C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9\data

Полистал и нашёл решение вместо **localhost** в "jdbc:postgresql://**localhost**:5432/test", "postgres", "password"); нужно указать **127.0.0.1** результат будет вот таким  **"jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/test", "postgres", "password");**

Comment: Это связано с вашими настройкам postgres.  В частности pg_hba.conf

Answer (score 0):

[08001] Подсоединение по адресу localhost:5432 отклонено. Проверьте что хост и порт указаны правильно и что postmaster принимает TCP/IP-подсоединения.
Подсоединение по адресу localhost:5432 отклонено. Проверьте что хост и порт указаны правильно и что postmaster принимает TCP/IP-подсоединения.